# How to show incoming call notification in android application

Tags: android

I want to display one dialog box after incoming call, so that I can run my application in background while receiving call.

How to catch that incoming call in android application???

Answer (score 7):

In AndroidManifest.xml you shoud make a receiver:

```
<receiver android:name="IncomingCallInterceptor">                    
    <intent-filter>
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"/>   
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and declare permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Then,

```
public class IncomingCallInterceptor extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override 
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {                                         
    String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);                         


    if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {                                   

        // Phone is ringing

    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this broadcast intent is what you need [ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED)